# Ranking vs funding for MS in CS at USA

Tags: masters, funding, ranking

Suppose, I have non funded admit from a top 40 university for MS in CS. Another university is ranked 150. The rankings are taken from *US News & World Report*. Which one should I choose?

Comment: Can someone else answer that? I'd say it's your choice. If you can fund yourself at the top-40 one and prefer it, go, if you can't or don't want to then don't.

Comment: To be concrete the university is Arizona State University and another one is University of Alabama, Huntsville (funded one).

Comment: I mean how different would the coursework be at universities that are 100 ranks apart  ? I want to get the best possible education since MS is a huge time investment.

Comment: I guess a top-40 would have harder courses and teach you more, but I'm just an MS student and don't know either much. The question will probably be closed since "shopping questions" aren't well-received here. Maybe the syllabuses on their websites will help. Also, it's still hard to tell you if it's worth it, that depends on how much you value your money and the course contents. In the end, if you're asking, it means you *can* fund yourself at ASU, so why not go there if you prefer a better-ranked program?

Comment: This is a strange question. How could we answer that? What are your priorities in life? Is either place culturally or otherwise (family, friends) important for you? Do you have money? Are you interested in adventures? Is one of the programs more interesting for you?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest that you ignore the rankings from any general ranking site. They look at a lot of things that are probably not relevant to you. In particular, they are probably not focused on MS programs.

Instead, look at the program you would be in and what are its offerings and its requirements. Look at the faculty in any specialty you are really interested in. Those are more important than the difference in "rankings" that aren't specific to your situation.

It may be that in one of them you would just be a face in the crowd and in the other you might be able to work closely with an experienced academic. In particular, what are typical class sizes in your program? How much teaching is done by doctoral students and how much by professors? Senior professors?

And, look, also, at the effect of funding, not just the fact of it. Graduating without debt is a really good thing.

And note that ranking of 150 is still very high, though I'll guess it is mostly based on the undergraduate experience.

---

You can get a better idea of the meaning of the rankings by looking at [their criteria](https://www.usnews.com/education/best-colleges/articles/ranking-criteria-and-weights)

Comment: I am now wondering if an MS degree in Computer Science is even worth the time even if one is fully funded.

Comment: Think about your long term goals. If it is academia, look for a doctorate. If it is industry, look at what the opportunities are with each degree you might obtain. Also look at the future prospects in industry, not just the starting position.